# How to mock a function in another function nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Trying to write a unittest for the below module in /utility/sqsThing.js. However I'm having diffuculty mocking the `sqs.sendMessage` method. Anyone know how I should go about this. I'm using the sinon library, and mocha for running the tests.

The function that I'm trying to unittest `utility/sqsThing.js`:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });
const outputQueURL = 'https:awsUrl';

const SQSOutputSender = (results) => {
  const params = {
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify(results),
    QueueUrl: outputQueURL,
  };
  // Method that I want to mock
  sqs.sendMessage(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error');
    } else {
      console.log('Success', data.MessageId);
    }
  });
};
```

My attempt at mocking the sqs.sendMessage method in a unittest `sqsThingTest.js`:

```
const sqsOutputResultSender = require('../utility/sqsThing');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });

const mochaccino = require('mochaccino');

const { expect } = mochaccino;
const sinon = require('sinon');


describe('SQS thing test', function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
        sinon.stub(sqs, 'sendMessage').callsFake( function() { return 'test' });
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        sqs.sendMessage.restore();
    });

  it('sqsOutputResultSender.SQSOutputSender', function() {
    // Where the mock substitution should occur
    const a = sqsOutputResultSender.SQSOutputSender('a');
    expect(a).toEqual('test');
  })
});
```

Running this unittest with `mocha tests/unit/sqsThingTest.js` however I get:
`AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal 'test'`.
`info: Error AccessDenied: Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied.`.

It looks like the mock did not replace the aws api call. Anyone know how I can mock `sqs.SendMessage` in my test?

Comment: Try sinon.stub(sqs.prototype, 'sendMessage')

Comment: @JonathanNewton Tried `sinon.stub(sqs.prototype, 'sendMessage').callsFake( function() { return 'test' })`. 
That gives me this error: `Error: Trying to stub property 'sendMessage' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [rewire js](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) it is a library that lets you inject mocked properties into your module you want to test.

Your require statement would look something like this:

```
var rewire = require("rewire");
var sqsOutputResultSender = rewire('../utility/sqsThing');
```

Rewire will allow you to mock everything in the top-level scope of you `sqsThing.js` file.

Also you need to return the value of `sqs.sendMessage` this will remove the issue `expected undefined to deeply equal 'test'`

Your original file would look the same just with a return statement.

```
//utility/sqsThing.js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });
const outputQueURL = 'https:awsUrl';

const SQSOutputSender = (results) => {
  const params = {
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify(results),
    QueueUrl: outputQueURL,
  };
  // Method that I want to mock
  return sqs.sendMessage(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error');
    } else {
      console.log('Success', data.MessageId);
    }
  });
};
```

You would then write your unit test as follows:

```
//sqsThingTest.js
var rewire = require("rewire");
var sqsOutputResultSender = rewire('../utility/sqsThing');
const mochaccino = require('mochaccino');
const { expect } = mochaccino;
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('SQS thing test', function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
        sqsOutputResultSender.__set__("sqs", {
            sendMessage: function() { return 'test' }
        });
    });

  it('sqsOutputResultSender.SQSOutputSender', function() {
    // Where the mock substitution should occur
    const a = sqsOutputResultSender.SQSOutputSender('a');
    expect(a).toEqual('test');
  })
});
```

This example returns an object with a property of `sendMessage` but this could be replaces with a spy.

[Rewire Docs](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire)

Comment: Works for me. Just had to change `myModule` to `sqsOutputResultSender`.

Comment: @dredbound fixed

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the declaration of `sqsOutputResultSender` after you have stubbed the `sendmessage` function

```
    var sqsOutputResultSender;
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });

    const mochaccino = require('mochaccino');

    const { expect } = mochaccino;
    const sinon = require('sinon');


    describe('SQS thing test', function() {
        beforeEach(function () {
            sinon.stub(sqs, 'sendMessage').callsFake( function() { return 'test' });
            sqsOutputResultSender = require('../utility/sqsThing');
        });

        afterEach(function () {
            sqs.sendMessage.restore();
        });

      it('sqsOutputResultSender.SQSOutputSender', function() {
        // Where the mock substitution should occur
        const a = sqsOutputResultSender.SQSOutputSender('a');
        expect(a).toEqual('test');
      })
    });
```

Comment: No, still gives me the same `AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal 'test'`. 
and
`info: Error AccessDenied: Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied.`

Comment: Could you move the call to `sqs.sendMessage` inside another function?

Comment: I could, but I'd still need to mock it in order to test that function wherever I move it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can access it but here is a suggestion: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jwcnewton/0d9b1671dcc3e199c5aafbf286454658) then your stub would look something like this ` sinon.stub(sqsOutputResultSender, 'sendMessage').callsFake( function() { return 'test' });`

Comment: Running that is still returning the same `AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal 'test'`. It's not replacing the function with the stub. I suspect that I'm just not using sinon correctly.

Comment: Sorry please see the update [HERE](https://gist.github.com/jwcnewton/0d9b1671dcc3e199c5aafbf286454658)

Comment: The example wasn't returning the result of `sendMessage` @dredbound

Comment: It's still not mocking it, although instead of undefined I now get. `AssertionError: expected { Object (domain, service, ...) } to deeply equal 'test'`  and also the same AWS `info: Error AccessDenied:` as before.

Comment: Could you replace the `.callsFake( function() { return 'test' });` with ` .returns('test');`

Comment: Not one for defeat! I created a new example [Here](https://gist.github.com/jwcnewton/3f38c92f2691440265468271d0f470b3) using `rewire.js` Sinon is not great a setting internals and generally you shouldn't change your functions to pass unit tests, It is using the same code as before but the import statement is wrapped in rewire.

Comment: Should probably add do `npm install rewire` also [Docs on rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire)

Comment: Also if you are getting `expected undefined to deeply equal 'test'` it's because your function doesn't return the stubbed result of `sqsOutputResultSender.SQSOutputSender('a');`

Comment: The rewired solution works with a few tweaks. Post it here and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @dredbound Fantastic! Sinon isn't able to access all the top level properties and each test must have been overwriting the stubed function.